# Multiply lines rows into one row - problems

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, moodle, entity-attribute-value

mdl_course which looks like this

```
id name
1  Course name
2  Other Name
3  Third name
```

second table i have mdl_scorm_scoes_track

```
id, course_id,meta_key,meta_value
1     1          score     100
1     1          status     passed
1     1          sesion_start xyz
```

and im trying to pull ony 2 meta keys out of 200 for each course
to get smth like this

```
id, course name, course_id, score status
1      Course name    1      100    passed
```

and i cant get this to work. i get to much rows with empty data

Here is exmaple what i tried to do
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q8drxvhaY86BuiFrggxYWK/2

You got two tables there mdl_course , mdl_scorm_scoes_track

```
SELECT sct.id,c.fullname,sct.userid,
       max(case when sct.element ='cmi.core.lesson_status' then sct.VALUE end) AS STATUS,
  max(case when sct.element ='cmi.core.score.raw' then sct.VALUE end) AS score
FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track sct
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = sct.scormid WHERE sct.USERid = 2 
group BY sct.id;
```

I get to much empty rows

```
id  fullname    userid  STATUS  score
2993    SCORM z JS  2            100
2996    SCORM z JS  2   passed  
3019    SCORM z JS  2   incomplete  
3022    SCORM z JS  2             75
3025    SCORM z JS  2   passed  
3217    SCORM z JS  2            100
3220    SCORM z JS  2   passed
```

2993 and 2996 should be one row 3022 and 3025 also and 3217 and 3220.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove many rows that you are not interested in by adding the condition

```
sct.element IN ('cmi.core.lesson_status', 'cmi.core.score.raw')
```

in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE 
  sct.USERid = 2 
  AND 
  sct.element IN ('cmi.core.lesson_status', 'cmi.core.score.raw')
```

Also you need to have in the `group by` clause all the non aggregated columns that you select:

```
SELECT 
  sct.id,
  c.fullname,
  sct.userid,
  max(case when sct.element ='cmi.core.lesson_status' then sct.VALUE end) AS STATUS,
  max(case when sct.element ='cmi.core.score.raw' then sct.VALUE end) AS score
FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track sct JOIN mdl_course c 
ON c.id = sct.scormid 
WHERE sct.USERid = 2 
AND sct.element IN ('cmi.core.lesson_status', 'cmi.core.score.raw') 
group BY sct.id, c.fullname, sct.userid
```

If this is not the grouping that you want, then maybe you need to rethink about it.

Comment: id 2993 and 2996 should be one row 3022 and 3025 also and 3217 and 3220.

Comment: Why these pairs? Is there a logic to apply?

Comment: You need to look into mdl_scorm_scoes_track table. You will see there are plenty key -> value rows with same id (scoid) i just want to get few rows data and combine them into one row.

Comment: Look at this example - this is exacly that data i need to combine in to one row.https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q8drxvhaY86BuiFrggxYWK/4

Comment: ok i have it You need to group by attempt so the full sql will be : SELECT 
  sct.id,
  c.fullname,
  sct.userid,
  sct.attempt,
  max(case when sct.element ='cmi.core.lesson_status' then sct.VALUE end) AS STATUS,
  max(case when sct.element ='cmi.core.score.raw' then sct.VALUE end) AS score
FROM mdl_scorm_scoes_track sct JOIN mdl_course c 
ON c.id = sct.scormid 
WHERE sct.USERid = 2 AND c.fullname = "SCORM z JS"
AND sct.element IN ('cmi.core.lesson_status', 'cmi.core.score.raw') 
group BY sct.attempt